What source does "PMag.Osl." refer to?
The LSJ entry for σκόλοψ includes

“σκόλοπες φοίνικος” PMag.Osl.1.270

but the reference isn't hyperlinked, and the abbreviations list doesn't give a full name.
I can't find any connection between the Magdalen Papyrus and Oslo.
The Oslo Papyri Electronic System contains 4 items (papyri I 3, I 4, I 5, III 75) described as 'Magical', each of a paragraph or so in length. Looking at the English translations, the only word I saw that I thought could possibly have been σκόλοπες was 'sting' (of a scorpion, in I 5), but looking at the Greek in the image this turned out to be δῆγμα.
Can anyone help me identify this source, preferably an online version, but at least a full name?

Just a heads up, that's not a list of LSJ's abbreviations, but Perseus'. Here's LSJ's.

It is shameful for such a comprehensive dictionary to offer so poorly compiled references, indeed.
I suppose the reference might be to Papyri Osloenses: Magical Papyri published by Samson Eitrem in 1925, not the literal phrase, but in a modified form in nominative case.


I think given the agreement in line reference this is almost certainly correct. Thanks!

Glad to be of help.
